# Creating an Application on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

In order to allow Facebook users to log in to our (Android) Mobile App - I need to create an App Id on Facebook.

Ideally I do not want to use my personal Facebook account to create the App Id.
I would rather use a generic account which the company owns, and not individual.

Does Facebook allow a generic account that a company can use for this purpose?
What is the best practice for this?

Answer (score 1):

Use business.facebook.com to handle some overhead but in the end a Facebook user (not generic) must be used to be create and develop applications.